# python dictionary replace dict[] operator with dict.get() behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, inheritance, operator-overloading

```
my_dict = {'a': 1}
```

I wish for `my_dict['a']` to behave the same as `my_dict.get('a')`
That way, if I do `my_dict['b']`, I will not raise an error but get the default `None` value, the same way you would get it from `my_dict.get('b')`

In the case of `my_dict = {'a': {'b': 2}}` I could do `my_dict['a']['b']` and it would act as `my_dict.get('a').get('b')`

When doing `my_dict['b'] = 2` it will act same as `my_dict.update({'b': 2})`

Is it possible to do so that I will not have to inherit from dict?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `dict.get()`?

Comment: `my_dict.get('a').get('b')` will raise `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to *add* a new value to the dictionary each time you try to access a non-existing key:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: None)
>>> d['a'] is None
True
>>> d
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10f463e18>, {'a': None})
```

If you don't want the key added, create a subclass of `dict` that implements the [`__missing__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__):

```
class DefaultNoneDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return None
```

This explicitly won't add new keys:

```
>>> d = DefaultNoneDict()
>>> d['a'] is None
True
>>> d
{}
```

If you wanted to *chain* `.get()` calls, you'll have to return an empty dictionary instead, otherwise `dict.get(keyA).get(keyB)` will fail with an attribute error (the first `None` returned won't have a `.get()` method).

Generally speaking, it is better to stick to the default type and be explicit. There is nothing wrong with:

```
value = some_d.get(outer, {}).get(inner)
```

Using a `defaultdict` or a `dict` subclass with custom `__missing__` hook have a downside: they will *always* produce a default when the key is missing, even when you accidentally produced incorrect keys somewhere else in your code. I often opt for an explicit `dict.get()` or `dict.setdefault()` codepath over `defaultdict` precisely because I want a non-existing key to produce an error in other parts of my project.